# How to free up memory in Lambda due to numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError using pandas compare()

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

When I run this code in a lambda function in which the memory allocation setting is set to max (10240):

```
df_compare = first_less_dupes[compare_columns].compare(second_less_dupes[compare_columns])
```

I'm seeing this error:

```
Unable to allocate 185. MiB for an array with shape (2697080, 9) and data type float64 - Error type:<class 'numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError'>
```

I've run this code many times with smaller dfs without issue. So I began attacking this from a memory capacity/clean-up approach my assumption being: I need to free up memory. I use two snippets of code to audit my memory usage:

```
def print_current_memory():
    '''
    Gets the current process and checks current memory usage
    '''
    process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    mbs = round(process.memory_info().rss / 1024 / 1024,2)
    print('Current memory usage:',mbs, 'MB')
```

And

```
for obj_name in list(locals().keys()):            
    size = str(sys.getsizeof(locals()[obj_name]))
    mbs = str(round(int(size) / 1024 / 1024,2))
    print(f'{obj_name}: {mbs}MB. {size}B.')
```

The `print_current_memory` function does just what it says in its comments. The loop prints out a list of all local variables and their size. Using the loop I identified several objects that I did not need. (Strangely the summed size of the listed objects should have greatly exceeded the lambda limit (even before the error)).
[image]

So I delete those objects and garbage collect (I understand gc may not be necessary).

```
    print_current_memory()    
    print('Deleting first & limited')
    del first
    del first_limited
    print('Deleting second & limited')
    del second
    del second_limited
    print('Deleting both_df')
    del both_df
    print('Garbage collecting')
    gc.collect()
    print_current_memory()
```

After running this I see:

[image]

I am clearly doing something wrong since the current memory usage doesn't decrease. And that is my main concern: How do I decrease memory usage to make space for this new dataframe? But Perhaps I'm asking the wrong question and need to question my assumptions like: Can I monitor current-memory-usuage in a Lambda the same way I would with a Window OS? Am I deleting objects the right way? My use of gc probably illustrates how little I know about it so am I using that correctly?

Comment: It is not actually possible to directly delete an object in Python. You can remove references to them, but Python provide no direct control of memory. It is a memory managed language. Without seeing specifics, we can really only speculate here

Comment: What specifics can I provide?

Comment: The specifics of what your code is doing a [mcve] of the problem

Comment: That's a lot of code and you'd have to spin up a lambda just to test. I'm curious how to free up memory. And if that's not possible (based on your first comment) then the way I am checking memory usage is wrong - which I provide that code.

Answer (score 1):

`del` does not properly delete objects, but simple drops the reference tied to the variable name being deleted. You must make sure that every other reference is properly dropped too.

Then you might still need to wait for garbage collection to happen. However with `pandas` and `numpy`, the actual data is managed in C++, and therefore the garbage collection should be immediate when the last reference is dropped.

Since you are working in an Amazon lambda, the data you transform does not need to be kept, because you just want your result out. Then it is certainly safe for you to use `inplace` to replace the original data with your processed data, and therefore free up space. Perhaps [such tutorial](https://medium.com/swlh/understand-inplace-in-pandas-e7ae3be3b0dc) could get you started.

Comment: "Then you might still need to wait for garbage collection to happen." Well usually CPython uses reference counting which frees objects as soon as their reference count reaches 0

Comment: Thanks. And I like the `inplace` suggestion (not necessarily inplace but the strategy of not creating new objects). But I'm also hoping for some clarification on the inconsistencies I'm seeing in the memory checks I'm doing (the loop and `print_current_memory` function).